# Performing different calculations for the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a salary column and I want to give a 20% raise to all the managers and a 30% raise to all the VP's. I'm not sure how I could join the table to itself and then make a different calculation because the select statement would remain the same with a 20% increase

```
SELECT 'Emp# ' || EMPLOYEE_ID  || ' named ' || FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||LAST_NAME || ' who is ' || JOB_ID || ' will have a new salary of $' || (SALARY +(SALARY*0.2)) AS "Employee with increased pay"
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE JOB_ID LIKE '___MAN%' OR (JOB_ID LIKE '___VP%') AND (SALARY < 6000 OR 
SALARY > 11000)
ORDER BY (SALARY - (SALARY*0.2)) DESC
```

Comment: Do you want to do a `select` or `update`?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using oracle and I want to select

Comment: you can do a case statement or a union

Comment: Thank you. A quick search of union and I was able to answer the question. No idea why my textbook doesn't even mention it.

Comment: A `case` expression is a better solution than `union` since it only reads the base data once. How do you recognize managers and vice presidents - through the `job_id`? That is a bad data model; the `job_id` should simply be a key (primary in the `jobs` table, foreign in the `employees` table) with no real-life meaning.

Comment: Yes I agree a case expression is the much better option. And yes you recognize it through the job_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE` clause.

`CASE` expressions let you use `IF ... THEN ... ELSE` logic in SQL statements without having to invoke procedures. (See [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm))

Your query should be like this one:

```
SELECT 'Emp# '
  || EMPLOYEE_ID
  || ' named '
  || FIRST_NAME
  || ' '
  ||LAST_NAME
  || ' who is '
  || JOB_ID
  || ' will have a new salary of $'
  ||
  CASE JOB_ID
    WHEN 'Manager'
    THEN (SALARY +(SALARY*0.2))
    WHEN 'VP'
    THEN (SALARY +(SALARY*0.3))
  END AS "Employee with increased pay"
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE JOB_ID LIKE '___MAN%'
OR (JOB_ID LIKE '___VP%')
AND (SALARY < 6000
OR SALARY   > 11000)
ORDER BY (SALARY - (SALARY*0.2)) DESC
```

In the `CASE` I used the values of the column `JOB_ID` assuming that 'Manager' and 'VP' are actual values of your table.

Hope it works for you.